# custom built -vs- commercial NAS devices

Tags: nas

I may need NAS in the medium term.

I can purchase a commercial NAS device, like a Synology or Qnap, but I have heard I can build my own.

What are the strengths of a custom built NAS, and the strengths of a commercial NAS?

Answer (score 1):

There isnt much difference between a custom build NAS and a commercial one.  Both often use BSD or Linux for the operating system.  Obviously, the commercial ones are more streamlined and easier to use for NAS, but custom builds are just as capable.  You are limited to the number of slots available in a commercial NAS, unless it supports managing other NASs.  A PC/server can hold for more hard drives.  There are numerous little differences, all minor.

In the end, it comes down to support.  If your NAS has an issue, there will be a dedicated team trying to help you.  If your custom built NAS has issues, you have to do all the troubleshooting on your own, or deal with multiple vendors.